# How to create a macOS SwiftUI Droplet/App? ...with SPM?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

If possible, how does one create a SwiftUI-based (not Cocoa-based) droplet app for macOS? ... and, as an extra step towards the newer Swift ecosystem, can this be done with the Swift Package Manger (SPM) instead of as an Xcode project?

An example use case, that I'm trying to figure out, is the Swift analog to the [AppleScript Droplet/App which can launch multiple VLC instances](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Play_multiple_instances/).  This VLC AS Droplet/App can be also used with the Finder Get Info "Open with:" setting.

```
on run
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/VLC.app"
    tell application "VLC" to activate
end run

on open theFiles
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        do shell script "open -na /Applications/VLC.app " & quote & (POSIX path of theFile) & quote
    end repeat
    tell application "VLC" to activate
end open
```

The StackOverflow search ["swift macos droplet"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swift+macos+droplet) returns zero items at this time.

A general internet search ended up with ["A Swift 4 ‘droplet’ scripting prototype, Dropsy"](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/04/13/a-swift-4-droplet-scripting-prototype-dropsy/) which is Cocoa based.

Comment: The latter half of [this](https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-build-macos-apps-using-only-the-swift-package-manager/) creates a SwiftUI app with SPM, but you will still need some AppKit APIs in the beginning. That said, what is a "droplet app"?

Comment: @Sweeper A "droplet app" can launch and process files (file urls) that are dropped onto the application icon without any additional user action. Sometimes no UI elements are shown.  Sometime UI elements (e.g. progress bar) are shown. A "droplet app" can start from a non-launched stated and quit after processing the file(s).

Comment: @Sweeper Some `AppKit` may be needed/required. However, an objective is to use the newer SwiftUI infrastructure as much as possible and avoid the use of outdated constructs like `NSApplicationDelegate`, `.storyboard`, etc.